# StackoverflowError with Apache Myfaces +v2.2.0

Tags: spring, apache, jsf, tomcat, myfaces

I tried updating an existing application to MyFaces 2.2.7 (from 2.1.7) by
simply changing the version in maven. When I try to deploy the app, I get a
StackOverflowError (below).
My app is running succesfully with myfaces-core/impl v 2.1.7.

```
    > SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getAttribute(ApplicationContext.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getAttribute(ApplicationContextFacade.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext.getAttribute(StandardContext.java:6913)
        at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ApplicationMap.getAttribute(ApplicationMap.java:47)
        at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.get(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:90)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.getMyfacesApplicationInstance(Application.java:100)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1245)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
        at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
        at javax.fa

ces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
........
........
SAME ERRORS TOO
........
........
    at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)

Şub 09, 2015 2:08:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

**UPDATE:**
pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.oys</groupId>
    <artifactId>oys</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-ALPHA</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Required By Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL driver connector library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.57</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
            <scope />
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope />
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-controller-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces Theme Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

**/WEB-INF/lib jar list** 
path->C:\tomcat\wtpwebapps\oys\WEB-INF\lib..

```
all-themes-1.0.10.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjweaver-1.7.2.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
dom4j-1.6.jar
ecj-4.4.jar
el-api-2.2.jar
el-impl-2.2.jar
geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
jboss-as-build-config-7.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-as-controller-client-7.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-as-protocol-7.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-dmr-1.1.1.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-marshalling-1.3.9.GA.jar
jboss-remoting-3.2.2.GA.jar
jboss-sasl-1.0.0.Final.jar
jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
myfaces-api-2.2.7.jar
myfaces-impl-2.2.7.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar
primefaces-5.1.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-binding-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-faces-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-js-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-js-resources-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-acl-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webflow-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xnio-api-3.0.3.GA.jar
```

How can I update myfaces 2.1.7 to 2.2.7? thanks in advance..

Comment: This is a sign of classpath pollution (duplicate different versioned classes in runtime classpath). Can you please confirm that you haven't manipulated JDK's and Tomcat's `/lib` folders, and edit the question to include a list of all JAR files which ended up in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the Maven-built WAR file? This way we can point out the conflicting JAR.

Comment: oh,i'm sorry.i updated.thanks in advance

Comment: It's unfortunate that you for some reason dumped the whole pom instead of listing the files in `/WEB-INF/lib` as asked in the comment, so an exact answer is still not possible, but the pom indeed looks fishy in first place. I'm seeing several container-specific libraries being included which are supposed to be already provided by the container. This has definitely classpath pollution as consequence, which in turn confirms the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: I updated again.Can you check pls.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

The following libraries are already provided by the servletcontainer (Tomcat) itself:

```
el-api-2.2.jar
el-impl-2.2.jar
javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
```

You're not supposed to provide them along the webapp. It would only end up in pollution of runtime classpath and conflicts between multiple classes of different versions coming from both the servletcontainer and the webapp.

Fix your build accordingly so that those libraries don't end up in WAR.

Comment: I remove this libraries, but no changes.how can I fix this problem?