# Facelet Richfaces Spring Security Tags

Tags: spring, security, tags, facelets

I am trying to get Spring Security tags working in my facelets page. I did everything per this document

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/webflow/2.3.x/reference/html/spring-faces.html#spring-faces-security-taglib

It asked me for spring faces jar and spring webflow jars. I gave

spring-faces-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webflow-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar

rest of my spring version is 3.0.2.

Now when I start my server I am getting stack overflow error with these

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getAttribute(ApplicationContext.java:236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getAttribute(ApplicationContextFacade.java:376)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ApplicationMap.getAttribute(ApplicationMap.java:47)
    at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.get(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:90)
    at javax.faces.application.Application.getMyfacesApplicationInstance(Application.java:100)
    at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1245)
    at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.application.Application.setFlowHandler(Application.java:1248)
```

I am not sure what is the version conflict. Any help is appreciated.

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SasMrm_Jars1</groupId>
  <artifactId>SasMrm_Jars1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SasMrm_Jars1</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I just gave up making spring tags working. I cannot afford to upgrade spring version just for that. I wrote security utility class to give me roles assigned. I am going to use that for access control. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spring-faces-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar` requires later spring versions than 3.0.2.

Look under the sub-heading '**Required Dependencies**' on the SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository page [here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.faces&version=2.3.0.RELEASE).

As you will see, mainly requires Spring versions *3.2.5.RELEASE* and *3.0.7.RELEASE*.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

For the `spring-faces-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar` that you are now using, here are the required dependencies:

[image]

Comment: That solved it. Thank you. spring-faces-2.0.6 worked with my spring version. Now my problem is it is too old of version, looks like it can not support Spring Security Tags. I am getting class not found exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils

Comment: Now I switched to Spring 3.2.6, Spring Security 3.2.0, Spring Faces / Webflow 2.3.2. I am back at infinite loop just like original post. Did anyone get right combination of versions to work with facelets ? I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: ok with the new error, did you see this similar problem here it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401127/stackoverflowerror-with-apache-myfaces-v2-2-0

Comment: @SuriG maybe post your web-inf/lib/ contents and your pom.xml as well and we'll try and get to the bottom of this, clearly still a dependency version issue. I've posted the new required dependencies in my above answer so we can check off your pom against this

Comment: Thank you @smoggers for taking time. I changed my pom.xml to version per this screen, still the same issue. posted my pom.xml

Comment: @SuriG in my previous job I used spring-faces and spring-webflow, struggling to remember how I had it configured. your pom dependencies look fine perhaps you just need to add dependencies, after all it does say 'required dependencies'. looking at the Maven repository they have listed 'compile dependencies' so perhaps try adding the dependencies they say are needed that you don't currently have in your pom, such as org.springframework.webflow.spring-binding? here is the link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-faces/2.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: @SuriG if still not working then try adding remaining required dependencies as per the SpringSource bundle repository I originally linked to here: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.faces&version=2.3.2.RELEASE